# APIs not available after adding AppProvider JAR dependencies in android studio

Tags: android, fleetboard

After integrating the API lib into my project using the menu item "Add AppProvider SDK Jar dependency" I cannot use any of the classes in my app.
I want to register an IVehicleClientCallback but the IDE cannot import the class.
The lib is contained in the libs folder and should be available for development.

I'm using android studio 2.2.3 in combination with the SDK version 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the gradle script has been updated by the plugin but the IDE did not recognize that and didn't sync the gradle file.

To solve the issue, open the gradle file, make any change (and revert it again) and perform ther gradle sync. Afterwards you should be able to use the library.